# Binary to decimal code improvement

Tags: python-2.7

I am totally new to python 2.7. Last time I worked on a little function for myself and liked to know how I could improve my algorithm. Is there anything unnecessary written there? (I didn't want to use the build in function on purpose because I am a beginner. But I know that these exists. I hopefully will keep this in mind for later.) Or do you know other methods to calculate from base 2 to base 10? That's the only way I know, or rather, how I would calculate it with pen and paper.

```
import math

print "Please enter a binary sequence."
prompt = '>> '
x = raw_input(prompt)
n = x[::-1]
i = 0
s = 0

'''bin2dec'''
for i in range(len(n)):
  i += 1
  if int(str(n)[i-1]) != 0:
    s += pow(2, i-1)
  else:
    s += 0
print s
```

PS: I'm currently on my way to work out the reverse algorithm. Stay tuned :)

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem.

Comment: It is indeed a working code. Didn't know about the code review section. Thanks for mentioning it. I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: First comment: use better variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
print "Please enter a binary sequence."
prompt = '>> '
x = raw_input(prompt)
x = list(x[::-1])
result=0
'''bin2dec'''
for i in range(len(x)):
    result+=int(x[i])*pow(2,i)
print result
```

- Firstly keep understandable variables while posting.
- The input can be converted into list for better traversing.
- This is more clarified and upgradable code possible with your concept.
- Instead of using math function `2**i`can be used .